# How to Late bind with T-SQL and the Statement Object?

Tags: php, t-sql, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am looking for a long term solution to accommodate T-SQL queries that need to use late binding. Late binding syntax with MS-SQL is a pain and is unique.

When it comes to T-SQL late binding we need to `DECLARE` and `SET`, like

```
DECLARE @id int 
SET @id = 1
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_id = @id;
```

Now Zend Framework 2 builds queries like

```
$select = new Sql\Select();
$select->from(['users']);
$select->columns(['*']);
$select->where->equalTo('user_id', '@id');
// Create the statement object
$stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject();
$stmt->prepare();
$stmt->execute(['@id' => 1]);
```

Now in ZF2's Statement object's `prepare()` method I can prefix my `DECLARE` and `SET` to the already existing `$sql`, like so:

```
 public function prepare($sql = null, array $options = [])
{
    if ($this->isPrepared) {
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException('Already prepared');
    }
    $sql = ($sql) ?: $this->sql;
    $options = ($options) ?: $this->prepareOptions;

    $pRef = &$this->parameterReferences;
    // change substr_count($sql, '?') <-> TO |-> substr_count($sql, '@')
    for ($position = 0, $count = substr_count($sql, '?'); $position < $count; $position++) {
        if (!isset($this->prepareParams[$position])) {
            $pRef[$position] = ['', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, null, null];
        } else {
            $pRef[$position] = &$this->prepareParams[$position];
        }
    }

    // <!-- Beg of custom stuff. I can grab the $sql string, that we built up here, with $this->sql, and prefix it with the T-SQL required DECLARE and SET. -->
    // We can get @id and 1 through the execute()'s call and the parameter Container.
    $prependSQL = "DECLARE @id int";
    $prependSQL .= "SET @id = 1";
    $prependSQL .= $this->sql;
    $this->sql = $prependSQL;
    $sql = $this->sql;
    // <!-- End of custom stuff -->
    $this->resource = sqlsrv_prepare($this->sqlsrv, $sql, $pRef, $options);

    $this->isPrepared = true;

    return $this;
}
```

Is this how I should be doing this? I feel like I am undermining ZF2's DB abstraction layer. Any direction or input would be great on how I am suppose to do this.